# Proper way to override dependencies within a scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm using Simple Injector. I have a background processor which is using DI from the start. It will pickup jobs to run, and run them. However, each job needs to run within its own scope so that I can override some contextual dependencies. For example, the job needs to run within a specific security context (the one from which it was created), so I need to start a new scope and override the `ISecurityContext` injection so the job will be properly secured.

To accomplish this, I was creating a new container (with the proper `ISecurityContext`) and starting a scope, then running the job, but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate thing to do.

**RunJob**

```
private readonly Func<ISecurityContext, Container> _containerFactory;

internal async Task RunJob(BackgroundJob job) {
    var parameters = job.GetParameters();
    var securityContext = parameters.SecurityContext;

    using (var container = _containerFactory(securityContext))
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) {
        // Run the job within this scope.
    }
}
```

**DI Bits**

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<ISecurityContext, Container>>(() => securityContext => {
    var c = new Container();

    RegisterDependencies(c);

    c.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
    c.Register<ISecurityContext>(() => securityContext, Lifestyle.Scoped);

    return c;
});
```

It doesn't feel right to me, but I'm not sure what the correct solution is.

Answer (score 3):

The Simple Injector documentation [warns](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html) about what you are doing by stating:

> **Warning:** Do not create an infinite number of Container instances (such as one instance per request). Doing so will drain the performance of your application. The library is optimized for using a very limited number of Container instances. Creating and initializing Container instances has a large overhead, but resolving from the Container is extremely fast once initialized.

In general, you should create only *one* `Container` instance per application. This not only holds from a performance perspective, but the creation of this sort of 'child containers' in general is littered with quirks and flaws. For instance, how to ensure that registrations are singletons across the application?

So instead, don't abuse the container for your runtime state, but store it elsewhere. You can use a `Scope` instance as dictionary for scoped state, but it's as easy to create a simple wrapper for `ISecurityContext` that is registered as `Scoped` instance and gets initialized directly after the scope is created as seen in the following example.

```
// Can be part of your Composition Root
internal sealed class SecurityContextWrapper : ISecurityContext
{
    // One of the rare cases that Property Injection makes sense.
    public ISecurityContext WrappedSecurityContext { get; set; }

    // Implement ISecurityContext methods here that delegate to WrappedSecurityContext.
}


// Composition Root. Only have 1 container for the complete application
c = new Container();

RegisterDependencies(c);

c.Register<SecurityContextWrapper>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
c.Register<ISecurityContext, SecurityContextWrapper>(Lifestyle.Scoped);


// Job logic
private readonly Container _container;

internal async Task RunJob(BackgroundJob job) {
    var parameters = job.GetParameters();
    var securityContext = parameters.SecurityContext;

    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container)) {
        // Resolve the wapper inside the scope
        var wrapper = _container.GetInstance<SecurityContextWrapper>();
        // Set it's wrapped value.
        wrapper.WrappedSecurityContext = securityContext;

        // Run the job within this scope.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use `Scope` as state, you can inject a `Scope` instance as constructor argument of `SecurityContextWrapper`. That removes the need to use Property Injection, but does make your `SecurityContextWrapper` dependent on Simple Injector:

```
// Can be part of your Composition Root
internal sealed class SecurityContextWrapper : ISecurityContext
{
    ISecurityContext _wrappedSecurityContext;

    public SecurityContextWrapper(Scope scope)
    {
        _wrappedSecurityContext= (ISecurityContext)scope.GetItem(typeof(ISecurityContext));
    }

    // Implement ISecurityContext methods here that delegate to WrappedSecurityContext.
}

// Composition Root. Only have 1 container for the complete application
c = new Container();

RegisterDependencies(c);

c.Register<ISecurityContext, SecurityContextWrapper>(Lifestyle.Scoped);


// Job logic
private readonly Container _container;

internal async Task RunJob(BackgroundJob job) {
    var parameters = job.GetParameters();
    var securityContext = parameters.SecurityContext;

    using (var scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container)) {
        // Set it's wrapped value.
        scope.SetItem(typeof(ISecurityContext), securityContext);

        // Run the job within this scope.
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you kindly. This is a definitely a great improvement.